# How to host my PyroCMS web page

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, hosting, pyrocms

So I have created my web page based on PyroCMS, adding some custom modules. Developing was done on localhost using wampserver. Now I need to put this website online, so I'm trying to test it using free hosting. I uploaded my project folder on webhost, imported database, changed database.php file for new connection settings.

But, when trying to custom modules from web site, I get message: "We cannot find the page you are looking for, please click here to go to the homepage."

What am I missing here? Everything was working good on localhost, I guess there is something I havent changed :/

Edited:
Maybe this helps - in control panel/add-on I get this error message:
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: models/module_m.php

Line Number: 479

Comment: some where paths are wrong, absolute or relative, maybe settings defined, not being psychic , that is the limit of my help. also most free hosts suck spend a few dollars, its worth it.

Comment: You'll need to post more than that. More than likely your settings are wrong in a config file

Comment: are you talking about database config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default URI_PROTOCOL is wrong, or not correctly detected by your host. Play with the settings in `config/config.php`. I have the most success with `PATH_INFO` instead of `AUTO`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```